# Grafana OAuth Authentication - missing saved state

Tags: angular, oauth, grafana

I have an issue with login via OAuth authentication. I'm new in this authentication method.
I have iframe where is panel:

it’s look like this:

[image]

I followed [this](https://grafana.com/docs/auth/generic-oauth/#set-up-oauth2-with-auth0) guide:  and set [aplication](https://manage.auth0.com/) on:  where i set name and Allowed Callback URLs: http://192.168.11.100:83/login/generic_oauth.

Then I followed [this](https://github.com/nbayramberdiyev/grafana-generic-oauth): , my grafana.ini look like this:

```
[auth.generic_oauth]
name = OAuth
enabled = true
allow_sign_up = false
client_id = i copy client_id from oauth
client_secret = i copy client_secret from oauth
scopes = user:email,read:org
email_attribute_name = email:primary
email_attribute_path =
auth_url = http://192.168.11.100/lzatloukal/grafana-generic-oauth/src/oauth/auth.php
token_url = http://192.168.11.100/lzatloukal/grafana-generic-oauth/src/oauth/token.php
api_url = http://192.168.11.100/lzatloukal/grafana-generic-oauth/src/oaut/user.php
team_ids =
allowed_organizations =
tls_skip_verify_insecure = false
tls_client_cert =
tls_client_key =
tls_client_ca =
send_client_credentials_via_post = false
```

After I click on Sign in with OAuth button I'm redirected on this error:

> login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state)

[image]

My grafana.log looks like:

```
t=2019-11-29T13:54:21+0100 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/d-solo/XKWwL-xWk/elinew-dashboard status=302 remote_addr=192.168.11.21 time_ms=0 size=37 referer=http://192.168.11.100/lzatloukal/test.html
t=2019-11-29T13:54:22+0100 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=302 remote_addr=192.168.11.21 time_ms=0 size=360 referer=http://192.168.11.100:83/grafana/login
t=2019-11-29T13:54:22+0100 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/generic_oauth status=500 remote_addr=192.168.11.21 time_ms=0 size=1750 referer=http://192.168.11.100:83/grafana/login
```

Somebody please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please be sure that `client_id` is your admin username and `client_secret` is your admin password. And verify that `token_url` and `api_url` return correct user details in Grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback URL must match the full HTTP address that you use in your browser to access Grafana, but with the prefix path of /login/generic_oauth.
so your problem here is that you don't redirect your app to /login//login/generic_oauth with the same state in the header of the request auth_url
so u can see repository(https://github.com/sadokbani/Grafana-generic_OAuth-NodeJS)
to better know your problem

Comment: @LukášZatloukal I am also facing the same issue, can you please tell exactly what fix you did for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because 'email' was not found on api_url result.

- Verify that 'api_url' returns email
- In Grafana Oauth config, try setting 'email_attribute_path' to the proper path.
  Example:
  email_attribute_name = user.email